# Is it possible to tone down the brightness of Adobe Reader?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

My textbook is a PDF file so I spend lots of time reading pages in Adobe Reader. The problem is the white background in Adobe reader is really bright and distracting. I've already turned down the brightness setting on my monitor but it's still a problem.

Is there a way to adjust the brightness somewhere in the Adobe Reader settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Acrobat/Reader, you can modify the Document Colour Options in `Edit > Preferences... > Accessibility`.

Below I have replaced the document colours with Yellow Text on Black:

[image: Preferences]

You can see an example of the changes below:

[image: Modified Settings]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac, gaming laptop, or have a decent graphics card, you would highly benefit from **inverting colors**.

On the Mac, you can easily access/change the keyboard shortcut from Keyboard preferences:

[image: Mac color invert]

...And on Windows 7, there's a hidden gem in Magnifier!

[image: Magnifier Color Invert]

Other gaming laptops and graphics card drivers may also have an invert colors hotkey/function, and they're always hidden quite well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how do i get to magnifier on Windows?

Comment: [Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> Ease of Access -> Magnifier](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-screen-items-bigger-magnifier#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: hahaha...i thought magnifier was in the Adobe Reader settings. Thanks.